# MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions

Tags: javascript, audio, amazon-s3, cors, mediaelement

I have a link to an mp3 on amazon s3 (the aws mp3 is set to public)
The audio player runs fine.

But when I try to make a visualizer, as soon as I connect to the audioplayer there is a CORS error. I don't understand why this should be so.

I have been using the MDN sample for analyserNode as the basis
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode

```
<audio id="audio-player-console" src="${AWS_songUrl}" autoplay>
    <p>Your browser does not support this audio player </p>
</audio>
```

Just to clarify, so long as no attempt to connect for analyserdata, the audioplayer runs the tracks without problem.

If I add crossorigin="anonymous" to the audio tag then I get nothing at all and the audio player won't play the track

```
<audio id="audio-player-console" src="${AWS_songUrl}" crossorigin="anonymous" autoplay>
    <p>Your browser does not support this audio player </p>
</audio>
```

My AWS CORS configuration after 'make public' has been set

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Here is where I try to connect the audio tag to the audiocontext for a visualizer, which is one it starts failing the CORS check

```
canvasCtx = visualizerCanvas.getContext("2d")
audioCtx =  new (window.AudioContext  || window.webkitAudioContext)()
var audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(aPlayer)
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser()
audioSrc.connect(analyser)
analyser.fftSize = 2048
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength)
analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray)
```

I just don't know what I can do. I have set the AWS config to public, allow all origins and all headers

Comment: I've has this same problem forever. I've spent many hours over several months trying to figure this out. I've asked two SO questions (each receiving upvotes) and I just asked a question on askubuntu.com . I hope I'll figure out a solution soon which I can then repost here.

Comment: I believed the problem was related to the fact that the visualizer node causes a second cors check after the audio tag has already made one. At this point the file is in a different location and thus fails the cors check. But I am not really sure about this.  I worked around it by abandoning the audio tag completely and only using the audiocontext object for the complete player: joegrundman.github.io/gplayer-react/

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out what to do after hours and hours of research and experimenting. There is very little documentation, as of this writing, available online showing how to do this. I hope people will find this helpful.

**Understanding CORS:**

CORS is an acronym for Cross Origin Resoruce Sharing. CORS is a new standard for sharing/accessing information between different domains. CORS basically is a method of using server headers to tell the browser if it is permitted to access or interact with a specific file on another server. While you can load most things without worrying about CORS (like images, audio, videos, and even other web pages), interaction with these elements requires special permission from the server. In my case, I was attempting to read frequencies from an audio file on another server. In this instance, I was attempting to access information which required authorization from special headers on the server.

Browser support is very good but, if you are supporting older browsers, you may want to see support tables here (http://caniuse.com/#search=cors)

**What I did:**

Enabled the use of .htaccess (I think you can accomplish the same thing with apache2.conf or 000-default.conf but .htaccess files are much easier to edit and maintain). These files are used to set headers and settings for apache. I enabled the use of .htaccess files by going to /etc/apache2/ and edited apache2.conf. Make sure your  entry matches the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I set the headers in my .htaccess file to allow access from Codepen. Create a .htaccess file in the same directory as the file you want to share. You only want to share what you have to or you might create a security risk. Type this in your .htaccess file:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://websiteWantingToAccessYourFile.com"`.

Save your file.
Restart Apache with this command sudo service apache2 restart. Enter your password if prompted.
With the audio, I added the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute. You can read more about CORS settings (crossorigin) here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) I imagine you can set this with ajax and xhr requests.
Different versions of apache may have different file names or standards. Check to make sure this is correct for your version. I am running Apache 2.4.18 on my Ubuntu server.

Please tell me if this can be improved. I have spent a lot of time understanding this but I am not an expert. Post your questions or suggestions in the comments. :)

Comment: Can you post the code for setting the crossorigin="anonymous" attribute?

Comment: Try `<audio src='mySrc' crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>`

Comment: @RyanGross I tried that previously but forgot to mention it in my answer. The audio loaded and played but the analyzer was denied access to the frequency data.

Comment: @jylopez See the above comment.